# Javascript image gallery for mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, image-gallery, touch-event

I want to make an image gallery for mobile with similar functionality to Flickr.

I'd like for it to move an image on touchmove depending on the direction your finger moves, and if you make a small swipe gesture, I'd like it to move the image all the way over, or if the swipe wasn't big enough, move the div back to its starting position on the x axis.

I know what the logic would look like, I'm just unsure of the syntax to use.

I think it'd be something like this:

On touchstart
-Assign variable for x position of touchstart

On touchmove
-Assign variable for x position of touchmove
-assign a variable for touchmove minus touchstart
- add (touchmove minus touchstart) to the current x position of a div

On touchend
- if touchmove => touchstart + 50px
    then add 1000px - (touchmove-touchstart) to the divs x position

-else if touchmove =< touchstart - 50px
    then minus 1000px + (touchmove - touchstart) from the divs x position

Else
    Minus (touchmove - touchstart) from the x position of the div

Can anyone translate this^^^ to javascript?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really up to the challenge, there is a lot of things to consider. You will need to make it platform independent, decide whether to animate with JavaScript, CSS3 animations or a bit of both. It will need to be responsive and allow the images to be loaded on demand etc. What about backwards compatibility?

You will also need to work in some clever logic that doesn't just detect the distance between the touchstart and touchmove but also the speed this was done. For example the user could flick their finger a short distance very fast causing a transition to occur or could move their finger a long distance very slowly causing a transition to not occur (within limits).

**So to answer your question**, no this will not just animate by itself. It will not move smoothly without some clever and efficient JavaScript or [CSS3 animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp).

I would recommend using one of the MANY JQuery libraries that already exist to do this for you. There are a number of free libraries out there that work great. After a quick search I found this one:

http://www.photoswipe.com/, which seems to do exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: if the x position of the div is being changed based on the current position of your finger during touchmove, then it will move at whatever speed your finger moves, and in terms of having it play forward or backwards onTouchend if the swipe was big enough, I would probably want it to play forward at a set rate and ease out.

Ideally, I'd like to not use a library or plugin of any kind. I want to just use plain javascript, but I'll check out photoswipe and see if I like it.

Comment: Okay after looking at it, I have a few questions about it. It obviously runs really well and is compatible with all browsers etc... but how can I change the styles for it? also, is it possible to only use the slideshow portion but not the thumbnails? If I can totally customize it in that way, I'd be much more interested. Mainly, I want to maximize my control over how it all looks and acts, which is why I'd prefer to code it all by hand, but if I can change the css for everything and only use the parts I want to use, then I'll probably go with it.

Comment: just answered one question for myself, it is possible to just use the slideshow with no thumbnails.

Comment: I can't say I've ever used photoswipe I just found it as a top result in a search. However, it looks to be well implemented with css styles so you can customise it to how you like. Just modify the css files that come with it and you will be well on your way. There are other options as well such as setting a "target" so it doesn't fill the entire screen, just the size of the target. You'll need to have a bit of a play around with it. Hope I have at least pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: I've been playing with it all night, it's sort of cool, but it's very annoying trying to sort through all of their pre-written code to change simple things. I'd much rather just write my own.